# Removing elements that appear in one array from another array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of available items:

`const items = [{id: 1, title: Item 1}, {id: 2, title: Item 2}, {id: 3, title: Item 3}]`

and an array of items that my user has purchased:

`const purchasedItems = [{id: 1, title: Item 1}, {id: 2, title: Item 2}]`

I want to display an array of items that are still available to them to purchase that they haven't bought yet, i.e. just item 3 in this case. So I want an array returned with just Item 3 in it.

I have tried:

```
const availableItems = items.filter(
    (item) => !purchasedItems.includes(item)
  )
```

However this just returns a list of all the items again.

Think I must be missing something quite obvious, any help appreciated!

Comment: change `.includes()` to `.findIndex()` and use a callback

Comment: Please try this: `const remainingItems = items.filter(({ id }) => (!(purchasedItems.some(x => x.id === id))));`. It uses `.filter` to pick `id` from `items` array and retain only those which do not have a corresponding element in `purchasedItems` array.

Answer (score 2):

`includes` won't work here because it will only compare the items with a strict equality (as in `item1 === item2`). It will only works if your items are the same objects with the same reference.

A little example:

```
const obj1 = { test: 1 };
const obj2 = obj1;
const obj3 = { test: 1 };

console.log(obj1 === obj2); // true
console.log(obj1 === obj3); // false
```

So, in your case, you have to do a more complex work in your filter function:

```
const availableItems = items.filter(item1 => !purchasedItems.some(item2 => item1.id === item2.id));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of includes

```js
const items = [{ id: 1, title: 'Item 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'Item 2' }, { id: 3, title: 'Item 3' }]

const purchasedItems = [{ id: 1, title: 'Item 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'Item 2' }]

const availableItems = items.filter((item) => (purchasedItems.findIndex(purchasedItem => purchasedItem.id === item.id) == -1))

console.log(availableItems)
```